# In eclipse , program running already but console not open after press Run or Ctrl+f11 but with other program when I press Run ,console window is open

Tags: java, eclipse, console

Using Eclipse, I made a program (sum.java) to sum n natural number but when I run this program it runs in background, Console window is not open after press Run or Ctrl+f11 . But when I run other Operation in same (sum.java) it shows console window.

When I hover over the "Run", button, it says "Run [program name here] (already running)" instead of "Run [program name here]".

**UPDATE IN DETAIL**
Problem occurs when we calculate large operation which run on console window over 3 minutes or more. For Example : **CALCULATE SUM OF N NATURAL NUMBER (N is Number entered by user to calculate sum from 0 to N). In this, when user enter 10000000 etc.** So, console window start calculate sum according to code which take some time and process is running which you can see in console window .if you close the console by clicking ( × ) button. Now, again run same program then console window not open but if you Hover on Run button in Eclipse IDE you see the message ( classname (running already)) .if you again run this program/code you get same thing . Now, you **go to WINDOW > SHOW VIEW > CONSOLE** after clicking these steps Console window is open and you can entered any Number for Sum and you get output in console but in this.you have to open Console window manually after Run your code which is not easy for whole time .you can also pinned console but sometimes it's cover desktop space.

**ERROR**
Popup window is generally comeup when we run program in eclipse but in this case popup window is comes with error but program run after open Console window manually by [window>showview>Console]
**IN POPUP WINDOW HEADING [Error in Workspace]**
**UDER POPUP WINDOW [Error in Program]**

Can anyone tell me why this would happen?

Please tell if possible or you can provide any link of the same problem.

Comment: Could be code flow is caught in an Infinite loop.

Comment: suspecting as @DevilsHnd mentioned. Provide your code for better understanding for the readers.

Comment: DevilsHnd , yes I made a program to sum n natural number . When I entered number in thousand like 1000 to 5000 ,it works and console window is open after running this program .but when I entered in lakh ex -10000000 , program is running continuously that's why after 1min I just close console window. After that ,when I run same program again by press Run button in eclipse then console window is not open but when I hover on run button ,it says" Run (Sumnaturalnumber) already running" . It's only open when I go WINDOW>SHOWVIEW>CONSOLE . but when I run other program , console window is open.